# Determine whether the following series is convergent or not

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Let we have the following series $$\sum_{p\ \text{is prime}}\frac{1}{p}$$

Is there a study on this series whether it is convergent or not , and if it is convergent what its sum is ?

Comment: It's fairly well known to diverge...see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) for some discussion.  It's not exactly easy to see.

Comment: By Chebyshev's weak version of the PNT we have
$$ C_1 \frac{n}{\log n}\leq \pi(n) \leq C_2 \frac{n}{\log n} $$
from which it follows that
$$ D_1 n\log n \leq p_n \leq D_2 n\log n $$
for any $n$ large enough. By Cauchy's condensation test, $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{p_n}$ is divergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following idea should allow you to *see* why $\sum \frac1{p}$ must diverge.

since all the terms are positive and less than 1, the convergence of $\sum \frac1{p}$ implies that of the products $\prod (1-\frac1{p})$ and $\prod \frac1{1-\frac1{p}}$.

however, it is well-known that for $s \gt 1$
$$
\prod \frac1{1-\frac1{p^s}} = \zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^s}
$$
so the convergence of $\prod \frac1{1-\frac1{p}}$ would imply that
$$
\lim_{s \to 1} \zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n}
$$
is finite, which is well-known (and easily proved) not to be the case